# Do you need to copy null char of char string or uint8_t array with memcpy in C

Tags: memcpy

Would this be correct to do?

```
 uint8_t a[14];
 uint8_t b[15] = "20200425123456";

 memcpy( a, b, 14);
```

It doesn't get accessed in C again, but gets sent wirelessly to a database.

Comment: It is legal code in C, if that is what you meant.  (*Well, technically `uint8_t[]` might not allow initialization from a string literal but all actual implementations I know of do allow that)

Comment: It would improve the question to add a language tag and perhaps some more context such as code showing how you will use `a` afterwards